# Subdomain matching

Tags: algorithms, c, data-structures, strings

I am working on a small plugin for a DNS server. I have a static list of domain (sometimes subdomains too) names:

```
gaming.xyz.com
facebook.com
mail.example.com
blog.example.com
```

I want to check if a subdomain has a match in the above list. For example:

```
abcd.gaming.xyz.com and def.gaming.xyz.com => gaming.xyz.com
a.b.c.facebook.com and z.facebook.com => facebook.com
```

My approach is to use a Trie with the domains inverted. In our example, *com* will be the root. *xyz*, *facebook* and *example* will be children of *com*. *mail* and *blog* will be children of *example*.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: @PhilipKendall Maybe another data structure that is better in terms of running time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trie is perfectly fine, but its complexity is not necessary. You can insert all your domains into a set data structure (e.g. an ordered array for binary search, or a hash set) and see whether any of the given (parent) domains is in that set. I.e. for when given `abcd.gaming.xyz.com` you would try:

```
   is abcd.gaming.xyz.com in the set?
or is      gaming.xyz.com in the set?
or is             xyz.com in the set?
or is                 com in the set?
```

Your trie approach is generally equivalent, just more complex to implement. The exact running time complexities will depend on the exact data structure you use. E.g. for a domain with *k* subdomains and *n* domains in the set, a hash set would give you expected *O*(*k*) running time, and a binary search in an array would give you *O*(*k* · log *n*) running time. The trie cannot improve over the hash set approach, but a trie-like tree has a theoretical advantage over binary search because the “n” items are split up into smaller searches at each level of the trie:
roughly *n* = *m*<sup>*k*</sup>,
giving us *O*(*k*<sup>2</sup> · log *m*) (assuming a log *m* lookup at each level). The exact value depends on the distribution of the data, and may in practice be more similar to a simple *O*(*k* log *n*) search. But again, this helps nothing if you could use a hash table instead.

Note that a simple binary search in an array can benefit from similar tricks as a trie if we match reversed domain names. For this purpose, either `moc.zyx.gnimag.dcba` or `com.xyz.gaming.abcd` would be fine. Whereas the first is easier to implement, I'll use the latter here for clarity. During a binary search we can keep track of the range of entries that contain our current key as prefix. So while we search for `com` first, we get a range of reversed domain names with `com` as prefix – for free. If that key isn't found we can continue to search for `com.xyz` within that range, rather than restarting with the whole array. And so on until we have a match.

The choice of data structure largely depends on whether a data structure implementation is already available (not necessarily a given in C), whether the set will change at run time, and whether you have any memory constraints. E.g. a trie will effectively compress the data, and tree data structures can be updated more efficiently than a sorted list. But trees also tend to be more complex and possibly have worse memory locality than ordered arrays or hash sets.

Comment: The list of domains won't change at run time. The application will run on Raspberry Pi. Not a lot of memory. Yeah, I would have to implement my own hashing function in C if I were to choose the hash set approach.

Comment: @psy [FNV-1a](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/index.html#FNV-1a) is a good hash function and very easy to implement. See also: [Which hashing function is best for uniqueness and speed?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/49550). For your hash table, it should be sufficient to resolve collisions through open addressing rather than malloc()ing memory for a linked list.